# Why the value of the text input appears undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I tried to make a text type input named 'pr2__answer', but when I view the value of it using console.log(answer.val()), it appears 'undefined'. I don't know why.
This is part of my code:

```
var country_capital_pairs = pairs;
var new_pairs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < country_capital_pairs.length; i++) {
    new_pairs[country_capital_pairs[i].country] = country_capital_pairs[i].capital;
}
var capital_names = Object.values(new_pairs);
var question = $("#pr2__question");
var answer = $("#pr2__answer");
var len = country_capital_pairs.length;
var Q = country_capital_pairs[Math.floor(Math.random()*len)];
var question_country = Q.country;
question.html(question_country);
answer.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: capital_names,
    select: function(evt, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
        answer.val(ui.item.value);
        $("input#pr2__submit").click();
        return false;
    }
}).focus();
```

The function answer.autocomplete doesn't work. So I think the problem is that the program doesn't remind that I am typing something in the input. Can anyone tell me why?
And this is a part of my HTML code:

```
<tr>
      <td id="pr2__question"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id=pr2__answer" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="pr2__submit" value="seeAnswer()" //></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are doing this in document.ready ?

Comment: try replacing this line: answer.val(ui.item.value); with: $(this).val(ui.item.value);

Comment: @SamuilPetrov It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your javascript code in the end of your html page or put you code inside of the function :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```